# nginx and codeigniter "passing uri" does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I've a small Codeigniter project and [passing uri](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri) (`localhost/project/index.php/Cfoo/funct/param`) doesn't work (404). The php-code is OK, because with lighttpd works.

My `nginx` config:

```
user  www www;
worker_processes 1;
worker_priority 15;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  512;
  accept_mutex on;
  use kqueue;
}

http {
    include       conf.d/options;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server {

        server_name localhost;
        index index.php index.html index.htm ;

        add_header  Cache-Control "public";
        add_header  X-Frame-Options "DENY";
        limit_req   zone=gulag burst=200 nodelay;
        expires     max;
        listen 80;

        root /usr/local/www;

        location ~ ^/~([^/]+)/(.+\.php)$ {
            if (!-f /home/$1/public_html/$2) {
                rewrite ^ 404;
            }
            alias /home/$1/public_html/$2;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
        location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
            alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
            autoindex on;
        }


        location /adminer {
            index adminer/index.php;
        }


        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        index index.php index.html index.htm ;

        location ~ \.php$ { include conf.d/php-fpm; }
        location = /favicon.ico { return 204; }
        location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ { deny all; }
        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** A server section:

```
    server {
        server_name orarend;
        root /home/zsolt/public_html/orarend_oo/;
        index index.php;
        add_header  Cache-Control "public";
        add_header  X-Frame-Options "DENY";
        limit_req   zone=gulag burst=200 nodelay;
        expires     max;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
            autoindex on;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ { include conf.d/php-fpm; }
    }
```

Comment: I see there is a close request. If my question isn't too relevant in stackoverflow and it would be better on serverfault.com or other please move it!

Comment: `server_name orarend;`if this isn't a real domain name then change it to one or if this is your local machine you could add something like `orarend.dev` to your hosts file

Comment: I've a line in hosts with `127.0.0.1 orarend`. With `orarend/index.php` works. But with `orarend` doesn't ("FastCGI: primary script unknown"). If I want "passing uri" (`orarend/index.php/controller`) causes an error: "rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to `/index.php/controller`".

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/Codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work, and you won't need to put `index.php` in the url

Replace `User` with your actual user's home

```
server {
  root /home/User/public_html/project;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not work. Maybe it's important: the codeigniter project is in `~/public_html/project`.

Comment: yea, you need to change your root to that, `root /usr/local/www/project`

Comment: Sorry, I feel I'm stupid but doesn't work :( Could you please edit your answer and post a whole config? Sorry for my stupidity :(

Comment: sorry apparently I miss read your root, I added it to the answer any way.

Comment: Oh, a seperate `server` section, understand. And what will the `fastcgi_index` and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` (because of php)?

Comment: no not separate, edit your current one, fix the `root` line and the `try_files` line

Comment: I want use `/usr/local/www` too (I've adminer and flyspray in this directory) so wouldn't be good to replace this.

Comment: Your idea was good! Check http://wiki.nginx.org/Codeigniter - and works well :) Thanks for your contribution!